# How to swap words in strings

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a string in my code like:

```kotlin
val string = "
|3
|<sup>3</sup>{{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}<sup>5</sup> {{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}
|None
"
```

The sample code is shorter, will have more `<sup></sup>` {{zombie}} and the mummy zombie might be like conehead zombie, buckethead zombie... there is like a hundred types of zombies

how can i change it to like:

```kotlin
"
|3
|{{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}<sup>3</sup> {{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}<sup>5</sup>
|None
"
```

Comment: hmm but the mummy zombie might be Buckethead Zombie, Conehead zombie, Ra Zombie... there is like a hundred types

Comment: burh who edited my post they did it wrong

Comment: i sead the mummy zombie might be like conehead zombie, buckethead zombie...

Comment: where do these strings come from ? why can't you assign `Mummy Zombie` to a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind regex:

```kotlin
val s = """
|3
|<sup>3</sup>{{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}<sup>5</sup> {{P|Mummy Zombie|2}}
|None
"""
val regex = "(<[^>]+>[^>]+>)\\s*(\\{\\{[^}]+\\}\\})".toRegex()
println(s.replace(regex, "$2$1"))
```

Comment: ok     i will do it

Comment: but why is there so much " in the code?

Comment: @cyao1234 If you got any error, replacing the `"""` to `"` or vise versa might help. It depends on your kotlin version.

Comment: my kotlin is the newest version so i should use one " right?

Comment: thank you soooooo much i finaly can finish my project